# IBM Notes - Create an agent to send mail on user input date

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I created a form which consists of a button to send mail notification to the user. I need a scheduled agent to **send mail on the user input date**. Thank you.

Here is the code for the button:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim incharge As String
    Dim Session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim varValues As Variant
    Dim varCC As Variant

    Set uidoc = ws.currentDocument
    Set doc = uidoc.Document
    varCC = "(the CC address)"
    varValues = doc.GetItemValue( "incharge" )
    Dim email As NotesDocument
    Set email = db.CreateDocument
    email.Form="project"
    email.Principal="(the sender address)"
    email.Subject="(subject)"
    email.CopyTo=  varCC
    If Not Isnull( Arraygetindex( varValues, "Employee 1" ) ) Then
    email.Body = "Message"
    email.SendTo = "Employee 1 Address"
    Call email.Send(False)
    Else
    End If
    If Not Isnull( Arraygetindex( varValues, "Employee 2" ) ) Then
        email.Body = "Message"
        email.SendTo = "Employee 2 Address"
        Call email.Send(False)
    Else
    End If
    If Not Isnull( Arraygetindex( varValues, "Employee 3" ) ) Then
        email.Body = "Message"
        email.SendTo = "Employee 3 Address"
        Call email.Send(False)
    Else
    End If
    If Not Isnull( Arraygetindex( varValues, "Employee 4" ) ) Then
        email.Body = "Message"
        email.SendTo = "Employee 4 Address"
        Call email.Send(False)
    Else
    End If
    If Not Isnull( Arraygetindex( varValues, "Employee 5" ) ) Then
        email.Body = "Message"
        email.SendTo = "Employee 5 Address"
        Call email.Send(False)
    Else
    End If
    If Not Isnull( Arraygetindex( varValues, "Employee 6" ) ) Then
        email.Body = "Message"
        email.SendTo = "Employee 6 Address"
        Call email.Send(False)
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

This code sends the mail once the button is clicked. Thank you!

Comment: Jamie, welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried already? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the button is clicked, just save the document.  Then create a scheduled agent that runs once per day, and do a db.search() looking for "project" documents with the current date, iterate through the collection and send them.

That's one way, there are many others.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Can you help me with the code for the lotusscript agent? I'm a beginner at domino specifically lotusscript.

Comment: Apparently, in Domino R10 there will be a way to postpone the sending of a mail. The server will then send the mail on a specific date and time, I assume based on the date/time value in some field.

Comment: That's not the way it works here on StackOverflow, Jamie. You post the code you tried, tell us what you expect it to do when it runs, and tell us what actually happens when it runs. We help you solve your problem in your code. We do not write your code for you, and we do not engage in conversations to give you detailed tutorials.

Comment: My bad. Thank you all for helping.